# List of Lists as result in list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to find a solution for a problem where I have to loop in a list for every element.

This is not the real problem that I am trying to solve, but I am using a simple example to illustrate the problem and what I want to understand.

```
aList= [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10,12]
```

I should regroup number divisible by each others.

result should give:

```
result = [[3], [4], [5], [6,3], [4,8],[3,9], [5,10], [3,4,6,12]]
```

I use this function:

```
def divisible(x,y):
 if x%y== 0: 
   return True
 else: 
   return False
```

well, to solve this problem using two loops, we can use:

```
globaList= []

for x in aList: 
  internalist=[]
  internalist.append(x)
  for y in aList:
    if divisible(x,y): 
       internalist.append(y)
    globaList.append(internalist)
```

I tried to write this double-loops in list comprehension, but didn't know how to make better way.

```
result= [[x for x in aList ] for y in aList if divisible(x,y) ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def divisible(x,y):
    if x%y== 0: 
        return True
    else: 
        return False

aList= [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10,12]

>>> [[x for x in aList if divisible(y,x)] for y in aList]
[[3], [4], [5], [3, 6], [4, 8], [3, 9], [5, 10], [3, 4, 6, 12]]
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what "do work" would be? That would dictate how you would make the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a helper function divisible:

```
aList= [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10,12]
print [[x for x in aList if y % x == 0] for y in aList]
```

If you really want to use a helper function you can make that more succinct by going:

```
def divisible(x,y):
    return  x % y == 0
```